# Python / Pandas - Count number of rows with certain index

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
     content
id         
17         B
17         A
 6         A
15         A
...
```

I want to count how many rows have the index 17 (in this case that would be 2).
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
sum(df.index == 17)
```

`df.index == 17` returns an array with `boolean` with `True` when index value matches else `False`. And while 
using `sum` function `True` is equivalent to `1`.

Comment: I'm getting results like [1 1 1 ..., 0 0 0]. I just want to know how many times 17 appears in index

Comment: @abutremutante do you mean while using `df.index == 17`,  you got `[1 1 1 ..., 0 0 0]`? Doesn't it work for the sample example provided?

Comment: you're right, it does. since my df is huge I tried to simplify here but apparently wasn't the best approach. anyway, I solved in a not very pythonic way: a=0, for i in df.index: if i == 17: a+=1

Answer (score 3):

## Problem: How to count the quantity of index label?

```
Input: # Your DataFrame
       test_dict = {'id': ['17', '17', '6', '15'], 'content': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'A']}
       testd_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict) # create DataFrame from dict
       testd_df.set_index('id', inplace=True) # set 'id' as index in inplace way
       testd_df
Output: 
             |content
        --------------
         id  |
        -------------
         17  |      B
         17  |      A
          6  |      A
         15  |      A
```

## Solution: Use api [`pandas.Index.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.value_counts.html)

Based on the document, `pandas.Index.value_counts` will return object containing counts of unique values and return a `pd.Series`.

so now, I can select the specific **index** I want by using [`pandas.Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) (not get confused with `.iloc`)

```
# Solution
Input:  index_count = pd.Index(testd_df.index).value_counts() # count value of unique value
        index_count

Output: 17    2
        15    1
        6     1
        dtype: int64
---------------------------------
Input:  index_count.loc['17'] # select the information you care about
Output: 2
```

Comment: There's no need to create a new, index, just use `testd_df.index.value_counts()`

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby level

```
df.groupby(level=0).count()
```

Or `reset_index()`

```
df.reset_index().groupby('id').count()
```

Comment: but how do I access the 17? df.groupby(level=0).count().loc[17]?

Comment: @abutremutante `df[df.index==17]`

Comment: Hi, my case has another column which is date. How could I count row on condition that date >= '2019-01-01' (for example)